# SOQL syntax for Trigger

Tags: soql

My Trigger will send an email anytime an Account has 8 or more cases created within 5 days.

I am receiving the following error:

*Field must be grouped or aggregated: Id (2:49)*

```
List<AggregateResult> AggregateResultList = [SELECT AccountId, Account.Name name, COUNT(Id) co,
                                Project__r.Implementation_status__c, Project__r.Client_Advisor_Email__c
                                FROM Case
                                WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:5 AND Id IN :Trigger.New
                                GROUP BY AccountId, Account.Name
                                HAVING COUNT(Id)  >= 8];
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You must aggregate all fields when using GROUP BY. This is mentioned in the SOQL documentation.

You might want to remove the non-aggregate fields and use a separate query to get the details for the account and project info that you need.